# Java 8 Stream, How to get Top N count?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, collect

I need your advice to simplify this code below. I have a player list with an ID of the games won. I want to extract the 2 best players from this list (the 2 players who have a better amount of match Id)
Once extracted, I have to return the initial list to do other operations.
I think it is possible to improve this code in terms of optimization or reading. If you can help me.

```
public class PlayerStatistics {
    int id
    String name;
    int idMatchWon; // key from Match

    // getter , setter
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<PlayerStatistics> _players = new ArrayList<PlayerStatistics>();

    _players.add(initialize(1,'John',4));
    _players.add(initialize(2,'Teddy',2));
    _players.add(initialize(3,'Kevin',3));

    // How to get Top 2
    List<PlayerStatistics> _top2Players = extractTop2Players(_players);
}

private List<PlayerStatistics> extractTop2Players (List<PlayerStatistics> _list) {

    List<PlayerStatistics> _topPlayers = new ArrayList<PlayerStatistics>();

    // 1. Group and count 
    Map<String, Long> _players = _list
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> (!"".equals(x.getName()) && x.getName()!= null) )
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            PlayerStatistics::getName, Collectors.counting()
                    )
            );
    ;

    // 2 Best Palyers
    Set<String> _sortedPlayers = _players.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Collections.reverseOrder()))
            .limit(2)
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    ;

    // 3. Rebuild list 
    _topPlayers = _list
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> _sortedPlayers.contains(x.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ;

    return _topPlayers;
}


private PlayerStatistics initialize (int id, String name, int year, int month, int won, int lost) {
    return 
        new PlayerStatistics()
            .withId(id)
            .withName(name)
            .withIdMatchWon(won)
        );
}
```

Comment: I’d use `.sorted()` and `.limit(2)` just like you do. I haven’t studied all of your code, though.

Comment: It's what I would do.

Comment: `'John'` etc. is not valid Java syntax. Further, your task is not clear. You say, you want to get “players”, but you are actually collecting `PlayerStatistics`, which could be more than one per player. It seems that you assume that each player has a unique name, but you should be explicit about it. Especially, as the name is the only actual notion of a “player”. If that’s all you have about a player, your `_sortedPlayers` set is already the final result, the top 2 “players”, so it’s not clear why you are performing that 3rd step collecting all associated `PlayerStatistics`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's state that your code is absolutely correct. It does what needs to be done and it's even optimized by using sets. It can be further improved in two ways, though:

1. *Time complexity:* you are sorting the whole dataset, which has a time complexity of `O(mlogm)`, with `m` being the size of your initial list of players. Immediately, you are taking the top `N` elements of your list, with `N << m`.

   Below I'm showing a way to improve time complexity of the algorithm to `O(mlogN)`, which means that in your specific case it would become `O(m)` (this is because `N=2`, so `logN=log2=1`).
2. You are traversing the dataset 3 times: first you're iterating the list of players  to create the map of counts, then you are iterating this map to get a set with the top `N` players, and finally you're iterating the list of players again to check whether each player belongs to the set of top `N` players.

   This can be improved to perform only 2 passes over the dataset: the first one to create a map of counts (similar to what you've already done) and the other one to create a structure that will keep only the top `N` elements, sorted by count descending, with the result ready to be returned once the traversal has finished.

*Important:* the solution below requires that your `PlayerStatistics` class implements the `hashCode` and `equals` methods consistently.

First we have a generic method `topN` that (not surprisingly) extracts the top `N` elements from any given map. It does this by comparing its entries by value, descending (in this version, values `V` must be `Comparable<V>`, but this algorithm can be easily extended to support values that don't implement `Comparable<V>` by providing a custom `Comparator<V>`):

```
public static 
<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>, T extends Comparable<? super T>>
Collection<K> 
topN(
        Map<K, V> map, 
        int N,
        Function<? super K, ? extends T> tieBreaker) {

    TreeMap<Map.Entry<K, V>, K> topN = new TreeMap<>(
        Map.Entry.<K, V>comparingByValue()      // by value descending, then by key
            .reversed()                         // to allow entries with duplicate values
            .thenComparing(e -> tieBreaker.apply(e.getKey())));

    map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
      topN.put(e, e.getKey());
      if (topN.size() > N) topN.pollLastEntry();
    });

    return topN.values();
}
```

Here the `topN` [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) behaves as a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) of size `N` (though we add up to `N+1` elements). First we put the entry into the `topN` map, then, if the map has more than `N` entries, we immediately invoke the [`pollLastEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#pollLastEntry--) method on it, which removes the entry with the lowest priority (according to the order of the keys of the `TreeMap`). This guarantees that upon traversal, the `topN` map will only contain the top `N` entries, already sorted.

Note that I'm using a comparator that first sorts the `TreeMap<Map.Entry<K, V>, K>` by values `V` in descending order, and then by keys `K`. This is achieved with the help of the `Function<? super K, ? extends T> tieBreaker` function, which transforms each key `K` to a value `T` that must be `Comparable<T>`. All this allows the map to contain entries with duplicate values of `V`, without requiring keys `K` to also be `Comparable<K>`.

Finally, you'd use the above method as follows:

```
Map<PlayerStatistics, Long> counts = yourInitialListOfPlayers.stream()
    .filter(x -> !"".equals(x.getName()) && x.getName() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));

Collection<PlayerStatistics> top2 = topN(counts, 2, PlayerStatistics::getName);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Federico. First of all, not to stop with problems of quote and to have taken the time to analyze my problem. And above all, to have the ability to abstract to solve a problem :). I just integrate your functions in my code and everything works perfectly.

Comment: @anthony44 I&#39;m glad to know my answer helped you, it was fun to write it. As to comments and observations, they are valid, at least for new readers. To be honest, I guessed a bit while answering your question... My guess was that `PlayerStatistics` was just an example and that the real code you have counts elements and groups by some of the properties. Holger's comments help visitors have a better context of the problem, so that they can better understand the answers.

Comment: Nice answer. Would `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` be preferable here?

Comment: @user7 I'm not sure, but it seems better

Comment: Your solution inserts *every* map entry into your TreeSet, kicking out the smallest element after each insertion. But all of those log(n) insertions are unnecessary - you can check whether an incoming entry is larger than the smallest entry in the TreeSet before inserting it.