# How to sort ArrayList of objects by timestamp and get last five elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a simple Chat app. I need to sort chat messages by timestamp and get the last five elements.

This is how I've done that. It works but I am not sure if this is the best way. Do you see any room for improvements?

```
private ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<ChatMessage> finalChatMessages = new ArrayList<>();


public ArrayList<ChatMessage> addNewChatMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {

    //receive new chat message
    if (!chatMessages.contains(chatMessage)) {
        chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
    } else {
        int pos = chatMessages.indexOf(chatMessage);
        chatMessages.set(pos, chatMessage);
    }

    //sort chat messages by timestamp
    Collections.sort(chatMessages, new Comparator<ChatMessage>() {
        public int compare(ChatMessage o1, ChatMessage o2) {
            if (o1.getTimestamp() == o2.getTimestamp())
                return 0;
            return o1.getTimestamp() < o2.getTimestamp() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });


    //get latest five messages
    List<ChatMessage> tail = chatMessages.subList(Math.max(chatMessages.size() - 5, 0), chatMessages.size());

    finalChatMessages.clear();


    //add new messages to the final list
    for (ChatMessage chatMessage : tail) {
        finalChatMessages.add(chatMessage);
    }

    return finalChatMessages;
}
```

Comment: You could post this question on the code review, since it works and it is not really a question.

Comment: If this code works correctly, you should post on our sister site [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @mychemicalro FYI, you can use `[CodeReview.SE]` to create a link in comments. This works for all Stack Exchange sites. The key is finding the correct prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 places to improve slightly:

1. Don't scan `chatMessages` twice (`contains` and `indexOf`):

   ```
   int pos = chatMessages.indexOf(chatMessage);
   if (pos == -1) {
       chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
   } else {
       chatMessages.set(pos, chatMessage);
   }
   ```
2. Use [`Timestamp.compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#compareTo-java.sql.Timestamp-):

   ```
   Collections.sort(chatMessages, new Comparator<ChatMessage>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(ChatMessage o1, ChatMessage o2) {
           return o1.getTimestamp().compareTo(o2.getTimestamp());
       }
   });
   ```

   In Java 8+:

   ```
   Collections.sort(chatMessages, Comparator.comparing(ChatMessage::getTimestamp));
   ```
3. Use `ArrayList.addAll`:

   ```
   finalChatMessages.clear();
   finalChatMessages.addAll(chatMessages.subList(Math.max(chatMessages.size() - 5, 0), chatMessages.size()));
   ```

Comment: Thank you. The project is still based on Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

A canonical streams solution, with the add improved would be:

```
int pos = chatMessages.indexOf(chatMessage);
if (pos == -1) {
    chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
} else {
    chatMessages.set(pos, chatMessage);
}

List<ChatMessage> tail = chatMessages.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ChatMessage::getTimestamp))
    .skip(Math.max(0, chatMessages.size() - 5))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

finalChatMessages.clear();
finalChatMessages.addAll(tail);
```

It is worth mentioning that sorting the whole list to only keep the last 5 elements can be improved in terms of time complexity. Sorting is `O(NlogN)`, with `N` being the total size of the list. If you want to improve your solution to be `O(Nlog5)` instead, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343325/java-8-stream-how-to-get-top-n-count/52357369#52357369).

Comment: Or `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(ChatMessage::getTimestamp).reversed()).limit(5)`

Comment: @shmosel that would return elements in the wrong direction

Comment: Good point. Though it's not completely clear whether the order matters in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java-8 features to sort the list :

```
Collections.sort(chatMessages, (o1, o2) -> o1.getTimestamp().compareTo(o2.getTimestamp()));
```

And since you want just the last 5 elements you can loop over this list

Answer (score -1):

Use Java 8 features:

```
//sort chat messages by timestamp and get latest 5 messages
chatMessages.sort(comparing(ChatMessage::getTimestamp));
int toSkip = Math.max(chatMessages.size() - 5, 0);
finalChatMessages = chatMessages.stream().skip(toSkip).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
return finalChatMessages;
```

comparing is a static import from class java.util.Comparator, toCollection is from java.util.stream.Collectors.

If your Method returns a List instead of an ArrayList, it will be even simpler:

```
//sort chat messages by timestamp and get latest 5 messages
chatMessages.sort(comparing(ChatMessage::getTimestamp).reversed());
int toSkip = Math.max(chatMessages.size() - 5, 0);
finalChatMessages = chatMessages.stream().skip(toSkip).collect(toList());
return finalChatMessages;
```

Comment: The code returns the *first* five messages, not the desired *last* five messages.

Comment: Adding `reversed()` makes it return the last five in wrong order.

Comment: This is better, but sorting in reversed order is not the same as the original question, because the order is reversed. You should `.skip(chatMessages.size() - 5)` instead, without reversed comparator

Comment: Also, the code doesn't replace the content of the existing `finalChatMessages` list, as needed.